# How to detect group email in Azure B2B in C#

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory

When a new user is being invited to my Azure AD using the code below, I come to an issue with distribution groups.

I want to test if the entered email is a distribution group email address.
Is there a nice way to validate the email address, such as an API call?

My fallback solution is to check the exception message. But this is not the best solution.

```cs
  try
      {

        var invitation = new Invitation 
        { 
        SendInvitationMessage = false,
        InvitedUserEmailAddress = "user@sample.com",
        InvitedUserType = "Member",
        InviteRedirectUrl = "https://sampledomain.com",
        InvitedUserDisplayName = "Sample User",
        };
                 
      graphClient.Invitations.Request().AddAsync(invitation);
      }
     catch (ServiceException ex)
      {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error Creating User : {ex.Message}")
      }
```

Comment: Hello @cpoDesign, May i know if  you are trying to validate the `emailid` like (exists or not) and format of `emailid` .

Comment: @AjayKumarGhose-MT no I am trying to check if the email address is a distribution group email. The email id would check if user has been already invited.